# Create <audio> elements and then play when table cells is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, closures

I have a HTML table with many cells, and I want to give each cell a class or ID so that a corresponding sound can be played. Since there are many cells, I want to automate this task with Javascript+jQuery and have less cluttered HTML.

So suppose I have a cell with the text `a`. I want to set the class of that cell to `click_sound_a` and generate an `<audio>` tag with the ID `sound_a` that will play the sound `a.mp3`. (I can also use IDs for the cells, but I think I will have some duplicates.)

I have the following code as an example with 5 sounds:

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
 // trigger play event on an audio element
function playSound(sound) {
    $("#sound_"+sound).get(0).play();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var sounds = ["a", "i", "u", "e", "o"];

    // create HTML5 <audio> elements
    for (var i in sounds) {
        $("<audio id='sound_"+sounds[i]+"'>  <source src='/downloads/sounds/"+sounds[i]+".mp3' type='audio/mpeg'> </audio>").appendTo("#page");

        // make columns clickable to play sounds
        $(".click_sound_"+sounds[i]).click(function() {
            playSound(sounds[i]);
        });
    } // end for
});
</script>
```

The problem is that when the loop terminates, all cells get the sound of the last element, even though they have been assigned the correct class. So in this case, every cell will play `o.mp3`. Where is the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
 // trigger play event on an audio element
function playSound(sound) {
  return function() {
    $("#sound_"+sound).get(0).play();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var sounds = ["a", "i", "u", "e", "o"];

    // create HTML5 <audio> elements
    for (var i in sounds) {
        $("<audio id='sound_"+sounds[i]+"'>  <source src='/downloads/sounds/"+sounds[i]+".mp3' type='audio/mpeg'> </audio>").appendTo("#page");

        // make columns clickable to play sounds
        $(".click_sound_"+sounds[i]).click(playSound(sounds[i]));
    } // end for
});
</script>
```

Explanation: it's a typical gotcha of JavaScript. Whenever the event handler you defined is called, it looks for the value of the `i` variable, which was last updated with 4. You need to use a closure to bind the appropriate value to the event handler.

In fact this is almost the same example as in Crockford's book: [Closure in The Good Parts](http://books.google.com/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q&f=false)